# ¿Cómo pasa este tipo de consulta sql?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Tengo esta consulta**

```
 SELECT f.idFactura, f.numeroFactura, b.nombre AS ban, c.razonSocial AS cli 
 FROM facturas AS f 
 INNER JOIN bancos AS b ON b.idb = f.idb
 INNER JOIN clientes AS c ON c.idc = f.idc
```

**y la quiero pasar a este tipo de consulta**

```
$facturas = DB::table('facturas')->select('idFactura','numeroFactura','idb','idc')->get();

return $facturas;
```

El resultado seria algo a si

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les Agradecería mucho si me pudieran explicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es 1:1 solo quiero saber como meter los inner join y hacer referencia a las demás tablas

Comment: Le agradecería mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A través de Eloquent y sus relaciones podemos hacerlo de esta forma:

Debes tener los siguientes modelos creados:

- Factura
- Cliente
- Banco

Modelo Factura

El modelo Factura debe tener las 2 relaciones vinculandolo con los otros 2 modelos de acuerdo con la imgen expuesta

```
class Factura extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = "idFactura";

    public function banco()
    {   //nota1
        return $this->hasOne(Banco::class, 'llaveForanea', 'idFactura');
    }

    public function cliente()
    {   //nota1
        return $this->hasOne(Cliente::class, 'llaveForanea', 'idFactura');
    }
}
```

- Para declarar el inverso de la relación usamos el método belongsTo donde indicamos que un cliente y un banco pertenecen a una factura
- En el apartado de **nota1** que coloqué en el modelo los parámetros a pasar son:

  - Primer parámetro es el Modelo al que apuntas para hacer la relación
  - Segundo parámetro es la llave foránea que tiene el modelo al que apuntas y que ayuda a hacer la relación (es decir la llave foránea que tienes en tus tablas relacionadas)
  - Tercer parámetro es la llave primaria del modelo desde cual cual estás generando la relación

> Todo lo anterior se configura por que las llaves primarias y foráneas de tus tablas no siguen las convenciones de nombre que Eloquent espera encontrar para hacer uso, pero para eso se las declaramos de forma explícita.

Modelo Cliente

```
class Cliente extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idc';

    public function factura()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Factura::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Banco

```
class Banco extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idb';

    public function factura()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Factura::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora nuestra consulta:

- Primero del modelo Factura solo vamos a obtener los registros donde existe una relación
- Posterior con el método with *cargamos* los datos de las relaciones que posee dicho modelo
- A primer nivel del modelo que obtenemos los registros donde existe relación también hacemos un select de las columnas

Consulta:

```
$data = Factura::has(['banco', 'cliente'])
                ->with(
                    [
                        'banco' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('bancos.nombre');
                        },
                        'cliente' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('clientes.razonSocial');
                        }
                    ])
                ->select(['facturas.idFactura', 'facturas.numeroFactura'])
                ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Segun la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) podrías trabajarlo de la siguiente forma.

```
$facturas = DB::table('facturas')
    ->join('bancos', 'facturas.idb', '=', 'bancos.idb')
    ->join('clientes', 'clientes.idc', '=', 'facturas.idc')
    ->select('facturas.idFactura, facturas.numeroFactura, bancos.nombre', 'clientes.razonSocial')
    ->get();

return $facturas;
```